# How to achieve authoring a single package for per-user or per-machine installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.8

I tried all the scenarios for creating a single MSI for per-user and per-machine. Below is my explanation:  According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_installer_team/2009/09/02/authoring-a-single-package-for-per-user-or-per-machine-installation-context-in-windows-7/

```
    <Property Id='ALLUSERS' Value='2' />
    <Property Id='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='{}'  />
```

Results in a per-machine installation and the value of MSIINSTALLPERUSER is "1" results in per-user installation.

Now I am running a custom action which determines the user is whether admin or not and so changing the property value  to be {} or 1.

My problem is the value of "ALLUSER" is changed to 1 Before logging during installation. The log created shows:

```
  "PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'. Its new value: '1'."
```

But When i run by directly giving MSIPERUSER Value as "1" The log shows:

```
  "PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting ALLUSERS property. Its current value is '2'."
```

So please help me how can i develop a single installer for both admin user and normal user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you follow the rules here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx

The point here is that Windows decides how the install works based on the user's privileges, not you with a custom action. That's why the property values change. Follow those rules and it just works.

Comment: installer is returning  error as "you does not have sufficient privilege" if we follow that page.

Comment: What does the ICE105 validation say? What is the InstallPrivileges setiing?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367800(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am using WixUI_advanced dialog reference and  didn't set InstallPrivilege to Package.

Comment: My guess is the wix ui is overriding your settings.

Comment: Hi PhilDW, what should be the registry root for a dual purpose installer. can we use HKMU.